# How to reduce or eliminate Metaball speckles?

Tags: rendering, meta-objects

I often encounter a problem where the rendered metasurface is not smooth -- and often it's least smooth in Cycles. I like to make them shiny and discontinuities in the surface lead to speckled reflections (not the same as "fireflies" caused by light path stochastics).

What causes this problem and what can be done to reduce its effect?

[Edit: .blend]:

[image]

Evee:
[image: evee]

Cycles (note how in addition to the speckle problem, the reflection lines are not smooth):
[image: cycles]

A different one, close up:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure that those are some kind of reflections, it looks like some issue with shading, can you share this blend file with us?

Comment: Hrm... I'm using environment mapping, maybe that's related.

Comment: You forgot to include your textures **File > External Data > Pack all into blend/ pack resources**

Comment: Whoops -- I fixed that.

Comment: huh metaballs, when I try to render it with a bit better resolution like 0.2 it takes all 32GB of my RAM and 12GB of GPU VRAM and it still doesn't render... anyway, yes those specs are caused by your hdri, if you turn up your roughness to 0.1 you can clearly see that those specs are your light sources from hdri, it is basically like sky with stars if you use 1 metalness and 0 roughness... I am however not sure if you can remove light source reflection from the object, because that way your object shouldn't receive any light as well

Comment: Those black spots however are not hdri, those are caused by duplicated vertices or wrong faces in your render topology, to solve that you would need to convert it into mesh and merge by distance/manually repair it/correct your shading

Comment: Your comment about "light source reflections" and "sky with stars" clued me in to the Sun I had in that scene, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized my mistake. In this scene, in addition to the environment map, I also earlier created a Sun light source, and the Sun is the undesirable white speckle being reflected.